# Go Daddy email SMTP not sending email but no error

Tags: c#, smtp

I've recently purchased the essentials email package from GoDaddy and I am trying to set up sending email from my website via SMTP.  I have the following code set up.

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "mycoolwebsite.com.mail.protection.outlook.com",
    Port = 25,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@mycoolwebsite.com", "supersecurepassword")
};
using (var message = new MailMessage("info@mycoolwebsite.com", "myemail@test.com")
{
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

This gets to send and doesn't throw any exceptions, however the email is not sent.  I am very confused at why this doesn't work.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Is it just a typo or ‘Send(message)’ is outside the using?

Comment: This is not outside of the using, the parentheses are defining the MailMessage object but the using block is actually the block below it.

Comment: Oh snap... Right! :)

Comment: Have you successfully sent an email using their webmail (i.e. do we know it works)?

Comment: Yes successfully done a test on webmail and from my mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to require TLS which means using MailKit's SMTP.  You can get it using the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio.  Search for **MailKit** by Jeffrey Stedfast.

Documentation is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) as well.

Once you have all the references in place, use the MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient class:

- Set "smtp.office365.com" as your host
- Use port 587.

You will need to add this line after creating your smtp instance because you have no OAuth token:

```
smtp.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
```

That will do what you need.

Here's an example of what the whole thing should look like:

```
string FromPseudonym = "MySite Support";
string FromAddress = "admin@MySite.com";
var message = new MimeMessage();

message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(FromPseudonym, FromAddress));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Pseudonym", "RecipientAddress@somewhere.com"));
message.Subject = "Testing Email";

var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();

string MsgBody = "Message Body stuff goes here";

bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = MsgBody;
message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
    client.Authenticate(FromAddress, "Your super secret password goes here");

    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

You'll need the following namespaces to be included:

```
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Utils;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I unfortunately do not have time to test this tonight but will give it a shot tomorrow and get back to you!

Comment: I've tried this code and I am getting the following exception being thrown, MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: 'An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection. Do I need to set something up so that it works with localhost?

Comment: After following the help at this location, I was able to resolve the issue and successfully send an email from my new email address.  https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate  Thanks so much for your help with this

Comment: Happy to be helpful.  Glad you have it up and running!

Answer (score 1):

I've been where you are before.  If you are running the app from your dev environment, the emails will not be sent.  GoDaddy SMTP is configured so that emails will only be sent when requested from within their environment.

If you push the code to their host and run it, it will work.  The most painful thing about this is that everything appears to go smoothly, but the SMTP client just eats the request and leaves you wondering why no email is sent.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, that's super annoying that it doesn't work on localhost. Glad it sounds like it may be fixed by pushing live.  I'll give this a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Happy to help.  I pulled my hair out on this one the first time I encountered it.  Please let us know if that does the trick.

Comment: Try this for your SMTP Host: "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"

Comment: I tried this as per some other peoples suggestions, however I have no mx record for relay-hosting.secureserver.net, it just throws an exception "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server 72.XXX.XXX.197 (72.XXX.XXX.197:25), connect error 10060"

Comment: ok.  Getting closer.  I'll post another answer with what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing anything about GoDaddy's API, the only thing I can suggest, is maybe verify that the port is correct. It might require transport layer security, in which case port 25 will be closed.

For example, I think the office365 SMTP server (smtp.office365.com) requires secure SMTP and uses port 587.

Comment: i've ran a telnet mycoolwebsite.com.mail.protection.outlook.com 25 and I get a response of 220 XXXXXXXXXX.mail.protection.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sun, 17 Mar 2019 20:45:08 +0000, which would make me feel like it's working ok?

Comment: Yes I would say so. That only proves the port is open, not that it will allow you to send mail through it. You'll need to verify this with GoDaddy.

Comment: One other thought: your authentication credentials need to be whatever credentials you have on _that SMTP server_, not just some credential you may have established on your web server, or your GoDaddy account, unless they happen to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. If i use the PORT 587 it worked for me instead of 465 provided by go daddy.